# How can I make this toothed gear wheel?

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry, topology

This is part of something I'm doing, a mechanical part resembling a gear wheel with a great many teeth.

[image: shape draft]

All I can think of is to make one tooth, then use the Array Modifier to do a radial symmetry of 40 copies of it. How do I then join them up cleanly?

Or is there a different approach than this?

Comment: Maybe this YouTube video will help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TkqLlK9R9U

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: You can enable the addon _Add Mesh: Extra Objects_ in the _Preferences_, then you can add an object in the viewport with `Shift`+`A` > _Add_ > _Mesh_ > _Gears_ > _Gear_ and play with the settings to get a custom shaped gear object. Or build it from scratch with the answer by @moonboots

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do it, you can create this shape:

[image]

Array it 40 times:

[image]

Give it a *Simple Deform* modifier, Bend mode, 360° on Z:

[image]

Comment: Just to make this more helpful for the OP who anticipated this answer: are the segments joined cleanly?

Comment: You'll need to apply the modifiers, select all and press M > Merge by Distance, or if you want to keep it non-destructive, enable the Merge option of the Array modifier and add a Weld modifier under the Simple Deform   ;)